# Is there a way to configure columns in highchart to have zero pointPadding AND a maxPointWidth?

Tags: highcharts

I'm creating a column chart that has two series (Income and Expenses) in Highcharts. I would like to have no padding between each column and I would like to be able to set the maxPointWidth to a value.

I already tried setting the maxPointWidth to a value and setting the pointPadding to zero. But when I do that the columns have extra padding between each of the series.

```
plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    grouping: true,
                    pointPadding: 0,
                    maxPointWidth: 32
                }
            }
```

I expected the columns to be adjacent to each other but instead the columns had even more space but the maxPointWidth did restrict the thickness of the columns to 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set also the `groupPadding = 0` and `borderWidth = 0`:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      borderWidth: 0,
      maxPointWidth: 32,
      groupPadding: 0
    }
}
```

Note, that columns are equally spaced on the chart plot area and when you set fixed columns width then space between them has to be adjusted.

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5f614cjz/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.groupPadding
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.borderWidth

Comment: How do you adjust the space between them?

Comment: You can set fixed space between columns using `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` but then the width of the column has to be dynamic (adjusted to have fixed space between): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6029zo8d/